# Spacing Between Divs (Vertical) and Sizing of Sub-Divs to Hold Content on Page

Tags: html, css

Firstly, I wanted to thank all of the great folks here who helped me solve a ton of issues with my basic layout, syntax, and the like. I *think* I have cleaned up my syntax and the development of my CSS as well as HTML are coming along quite nicely now.

Now, on to the issues at hand. There are two that I'm working through now:

1. There is spacing between the top navigation area, and the image in the next div.  This only shows up at certain zoom levels, but I need to make sure it doesn't ever show up. I have tried eliminating the white space, and have made sure that all borders/padding are gone from this classes. The one thing I haven't tried is negative margins on the bottom of the Nav divs, but I would **really** like to do this without 'hacking' it with negative margins.

   [image: This is the 'nav with spacing' - which shows the actual black line between the divs]

   [image: This is the way it SHOULD look - and does look, on certain screen resolutions]

   **BONUS:** Why can I not get the topImage class (which holds the .png file under the nav) to be an actual 100% width? I have tweaked it a bunch, but I keep ending up with padding on the sides. It's not the end of the world, but I would like it to be 100% just so it flows with the top elements, and also looks a little cleaner when it connects up to `.bodySection2` and the `.section` divs that are the orange boxes.

   [image: As you can see here, there is a black (which is background color of that cell) padding around the image itself. I'd like to remove this.]
2. This one is kind of annoying. I have a class, `.section`, which is the orange blocks on the page. These are all the same, programatically and I did a bunch of fiddling with the width and spacing to get them perfectly centered within the `.bodySection2` div, so that I'm happy with. However, as you can see in the screenshot below, each of the boxes is a different size, even though they've been given the same Height % from the CSS. I realize that if I filled it out with text, they would adjust to be the same size, but I want to make sure they are the same size, regardless of the content inside of them. I have tried the Height: XX% (as well as making sure all parents have a % height set), but it does not seem to have any effect at all. Can you guys guide me on this one?

   [image: Mis-matched .section boxes in my bodySection2 div]

Fiddle HEre: [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnqo8jmy/)

Also - Any suggestions, advice, thoughts, comments, etc etc on the layout, color scheme, navigation elements, or whatever, would be greatly appreciated!  I am in the midst of re-branding my company, and obviously, the web site is one of the biggest things to promote my brand.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>Frick Solutions - Technology Consulting for Small Business</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/redesign/css/fricksolutions.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class ="container">

 <div class="navLogo">

  <a href="/index.html"><img src="/redesign/img/FrickSolutionsLogoWhite.png" style="height:100%; width:AUTO;"> </a>

  <div class="navElements" align="right">
  <li> <a href="/why.html">Why Us?</a></li> 
  <li> <a href="/smallbusiness.html">Small Business</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/servers.html"> Servers </a></li> 
  <li><a href="/athome.html"> @Home </a> </li> 
  <li> <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
  </div> <!--Close navElememts div -->
</div> <!--Close navlogo div -->
<div class = "bodySection">
<div class = "topImage">
<img src ="/redesign/img/NoteBookCoffeeforWeb2.png" style="width: 100%; height:auto; display:block;" alt="Let's Get to Work!">
</div> <!--Close TopImage div>\-->
</div><div class = "bodySection2"> <!-- close bodySection -->
<center>
<div class = "section" style="height:50%;">
<img src="/redesign/img/target.png"><br>
<b>A Targeted Approach</b><br>
Frick Solutions takes a targeted approach to solving your business problems through creative use of technologies.
</div><!-- Close leftSection -->
<div class = "section" style="height:50%;">
<img src="/redesign/img/arrow.png"><br>
<b>Guidance</b><br>
Providing guidance to small businesses on hot to get the best return on their technology investment and plan for the future.
</div> <!-- Close midSection -->
<div class = "section" style="height:50%;">
<img src="/redesign/img/speechbub.png"><br>
<b>Training</b><br>
Training for all of your staff on various technologies.</div>
</center>

<!-- Close rightSection -->
<!-- <div class = "section">
left text test
</div><!-- Close leftSection -->
<!--<div class = "section">
mid text test
</div> <!-- Close midSection -->
<!--<div class = "section">
right text test
</div><!-- Close rightSection -->
</center>
</div> <!--close bodySection2 -->
</div> <!-- close container -->

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {

  color: black;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;  /*use this to ensure left most content goes all the way to border of page */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 html {
 height: 100%; }

@media screen and (min-width:30em) { /* used to be 600 px */
  .navLogo
  {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #373737;
  width: 98%;
  height: 10%;
 /* border: 1px solid green;  */
   }


   .navElements
   {
   padding-right: 1%;
   padding-left: 1%;
   font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
   background-color: transparent;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 95%;
   padding-bottom: .25%;
 /*  border: 1px solid orange; */
    }

    .navElements li
    {
    color: white;
    background-color:transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
     }
     a:link 
    {
  color: white 

  }
a:visited 
  {
  color: white 
  }
  a:hover
  {
      color: grey;      
  }


 .bodySection /* This is used to contain the image directly under the navigation/logo*/
 {
 padding-left: 1%; 
 padding-right: 1%;
 padding-top: 5%;  /*this is here as a hack to make sure the bodySection div shows up under the navLogo/navElement divs*/
 width: 98%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto; /*forces all content inside the div to appear within the div */
 background-color: black;
 display: block;
/* border: 1px solid red; */

  }

   .bodySection2 /*This holds the content under the images (boxes with images and text) */
 {
 padding-left: 1%; 
 padding-right: 1%;
 padding-top: 1%; 
 width: 98%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto; /*forces all content inside the div to appear within the div */
 background-color: white;
 display: block;
/* border: 1px solid red; */

  }

  .topImage
 {
 clear:left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block; 
 background-color: black;
 overflow: auto;
  /*border: 1px solid pink; */
  }

 .section
 { 
 width: 22%;
 height: 90%;
 border: 4px solid;
 border-color: #FFB238;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 2%;
 float:left; 
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 margin-top: 1%;
 padding-top: 1%;
 padding-bottom: 1%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
 /*overflow: auto; */
  }

.container
{
  width: 100%;
  /*overflow: auto; */
  background-color: black;
  /*border: 1px solid blue;  */
  }

 } /*closes @ mediaedia screen and (min-width:30em */
```

Comment: On 2, you could use a fixed height, or make use of the flexbox propperty of css, which you have to set on the parent div of those containers (read `bodySection2`). I ll see if i can whip up the example in a fiddle for you.

Comment: I really don't want to use anything fixed (pixel, em) in my layout.  My goal is full fluiditiy and responsive design.  Once I have the 30em+ css perfected, I will do a 29.9999 and below, and that will be percentage based as well.   A fiddle would be great, I will also look into flexbox property on this div as well.  Thanks!

Comment: The first problem is because of your **%1** *paddin-left* and *padding-right*. give a fix padding value and you can use not fix value for width for your fluid layout.

Comment: Like I said to @Dorvalla, I cannot use fixed padding values.  This needs to be fluid and responsive, so % is the way I choose to do ALL sizing on this project.

Comment: Random side comment, but negative margins are technically [not a hack](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User's Dorvalla and user112344 had the right idea.  The only missing fix was the black space at the top of `.bodySection`.  What was causing this issue was that `padding-top: 5%` (from `.bodySection`) and `height: 10%` (from `.navLogo`) are two very different things.  The height in `.navLogo` is based of the the viewport, since `.navLogo` is a fixed element.  On the other hand `.bodySection`'s `padding-top` when used as a percentage is based on the width of the element.  This is by design.  According to the [box-model spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties):

> **<percentage>**
>   The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

An easy way around this (for your case) is to use [viewport units](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/05/simplify-your-stylesheets-with-the-magical-css-viewport-units/) instead (don't worry, they are liquid).  This coupled with removing your `padding-left: 1%` and `padding-right: 1%` from `.bodySection` fixes the other issue with your `.topImage` (technically you can remove your side padding on `.bodySection2` as well).

For your `.section` height using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) works great to get them to be the same height.  Just add `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-around` to `.bodySection2` and remove your height on `.section` and they will happily comply to your wishes.  Just make sure you don't forget the prefixes (`-webkit-` for Safari and `-ms-` for IE9).

```css
* {
  /* A quick css reset */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width:30em) {  
  .navLogo {
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #373737;
    width: 98%;
    height: 10%;
  }
  .navElements {
    padding: 0 1%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-bottom: .25%;
  }
  .navElements li {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  a:link, a:visited {
    color: white
  }
  a:hover {
    color: grey;
  }
  .bodySection
  {
    /* Makes the padding equal to .navLogo's height */
    padding-top: 10vh;
    
    /* Removed padding-left and padding-right */
  }
  .bodySection2
  {
    margin: 2% 0;
    
    /* Makes the .section's height match */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .section {
    /* Removed height: 90% */
    width: 22%;
    border: 4px solid #FFB238;
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navLogo">
      <a href="/index.html" id="logo"><img src="http://www.fricksolutions.com/redesign/img/FrickSolutionsLogoWhite.png" style="height:100%;"></a>
      <div class="navElements">
        <li><a href="/why.html">Why Us?</a></li>
        <li><a href="/smallbusiness.html">Small Business</a></li>
        <li><a href="/servers.html"> Servers </a></li>
        <li><a href="/athome.html"> @Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bodySection">
      <div class="topImage">
        <img src="http://www.fricksolutions.com/redesign/img/NoteBookCoffeeforWeb2.png" style="width: 100%;" alt="Let's Get to Work!">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bodySection2">
      <div class="section">
        <img src="http://www.fricksolutions.com/redesign/img/target.png">
        <br>
        <b>A Targeted Approach</b>
        <br> Frick Solutions takes a targeted approach to solving your business problems through creative use of technologies.
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <img src="http://www.fricksolutions.com/redesign/img/arrow.png">
        <br>
        <b>Guidance</b>
        <br> Providing guidance to small businesses on hot to get the best return on their technology investment and plan for the future.
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <img src="http://www.fricksolutions.com/redesign/img/speechbub.png">
        <br>
        <b>Training</b>
        <br> Training for all of your staff on various technologies.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

### EDIT

In order to fix the squishing of the logo (which oddly only happens in Chrome—and Opera, but no on really uses Opera) you can use `object-fit: contain` and `object-position: 0 0`.  These allow `background-image` like behavior, but don't use `background image`.  Chris Coyier at css-tricks.com has a nice, short, and sweet article for both [`object-fit`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) and [`object-position`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-position/).  All it takes is one added rule to your css:

```
#logo img {
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: 0 0;
}
```

While support for these two properties [aren't all that great](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit), since they are fully supported by both Chrome and Opera (the only two that need them to fix the issue) it isn't that big of a deal.

---

I took a moment to remove some of your css that was not doing anything.  If you were attached to it in any way feel free to add it back in.  Any properties that could be combined, along with any deprecated code (`center` and `align="right"`), were also modified.

Also a few suggestions.  It's typically a [good idea to avoid inline styling](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm).  You may want to think about moving the few inline styles you have left (I removed a lot that weren't doing anything in the quick clean up I did).

In addition to inline styles you may want to look at the semantics of your html.  For instance, your `.section`'s are a prime candidate for some simple modifications.

This:

```
<div class="section">
  <img src="http://www.fricksolutions.com/redesign/img/speechbub.png">
  <br>
  <b>Training</b>
  <br> Training for all of your staff on various technologies.
</div>
```

Could easily be changed to this:

```
<section>
  <img src="http://www.fricksolutions.com/redesign/img/speechbub.png">
  <h3>Training</h3>
  <p>Training for all of your staff on various technologies.</p>
</section>
```

Simply change your css to reflect the changes (remove the '.' in front of `.section` and make the h3 tag match your `font-size`) and you won't even be able to tell the difference, but your html now has meaning (and break tags shouldn't be used for positioning).  There of course could be an argument made against using a heading tag (which do you use? An `h1`? An `h6`? Something in between?) since there are no other used in your site.  Technically [HTML5 doesn't care](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections) though it's "strongly encouraged to use headings of the appropriate rank ...."  If that bothers you you can just use a `p` tag and use either [`strong` or `b`](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/strong-and-b-elements.htm) inside, similar to what you are doing now.

Another simple semantic fix would be to change `.navLogo`, '.navElements', and `.topImage` can all be changed from `div`'s to `header`, `nav`, and `figure` respectively.  Also, `.container` can be completely removed.  All of this affects the look of your site in no way, but adds even more meaning to your html while removing a pointless element (if container is there for an unseen reason then I apologize).

If you really want to try something crazy you could get rid of `.bodySection` and `.bodySection2` and instead wrap `.topImage` and the `.section`'s (or `section`'s if you change them) in a `main` tag.  Just add the css rules from `.bodySection` and `.bodySection2` with the addition of `flex-wrap: wrap` to `main`, add back the `width: 100%` to `.topImage` and move the `margin: 2% 0` from `.bodySection2` to your `.section`'s.  This removes two non-meaningful tags and adds one semantic one.  Not a big change, but it cleans it up a bit.

HTML:

```
<main>
    <figure class="topImage">...</figure>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main {
  padding-top: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.topImage {
  width: 100%;
}

.section {
  margin: 2% 0;
  ...
}
```

Just a few ideas.  There's absolutely no need to do any of that.

Comment: I'm afraid I spent more time on the suggestions/advice section of my answer than the actual solutions to your problems.  I apologize.

Comment: This was an incredible answer man.  I really appreciate you going into detail about the issues I had with my code, and how to fix them.  I especially liked the bit on inline formatting, and absolutely you're right, it should be handled in the style sheet.

I am going to try out the basic changes and make sure they incorporate well into my overall layout (which I think they will), and then I am going to implement the style changes you suggest as well, because its obviously the better coding practice, and will make maintainability a lot easier.  Thanks a lot man!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help.  Let me know if anything doesn't work and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Thanks again man!  I have really just pasted your code into a copy file, and everything works flawlessly.  I think I may want to change the navLogo and navElements to be contained in a 10% height fixed wrapper up top, just so they scale a bit better on resize of window (one of the things I've been really trying to focus on).  So I think I will try something like that (unless you've got a snippet handy!).
Two questions. In the bodySection, what is padding-top: 10vh?  I see the comment, but what does vh mean, and how is it different than %, px, or em?  Also, do you use any tools to diagnose css?

Comment: vh is a viewport unit. It basically a percentage for the viewport's height, rather than the width (in the case of percentage based padding) or parent height (in the case of height). There's also vw, vmax, and vmin, which you can read about [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/05/simplify-your-stylesheets-with-the-magical-css-viewport-units/). For looking at css I just use Chrome's developer tools (right-click and inspect element) IE and Firefox have similar tools.

Comment: I think I found the issue you were talking about with `navLogo` and `navElements`.  I added a section on a way to fix it.  If that doesn't fix what you were seeing then I'm not sure what issue you were talking about needing a wrapper for.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a CSS reset at the beginning of your style file for unwanted spaces like this:

```
html, body, div, img, p, ul, li, span { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I will be sure to keep my questions to one per post :).  I did just inject that snippet, but it had no effect on my spacing issue.

Comment: That's because you had not specifically asked your question. instead of adding those screenshots, just add the header section of your website and just the related part of your CSS file. nothing else. that's the right way of asking questions here on stackoverflow

Comment: Roger that.  I will re-author the question in a more targeted fashion.  Thanks man!

Comment: @BrianFrick Please consider upvoting answers to be thankful of time and effort people invest to help you solve your problems